# Why does gcc compile this and msvc doesn't

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

Here is my class

```
class ContainerStack{
public:
    int getCapacity();
    int getSize();
    const Container& at(int height);
    void take(Container aContainer);
    Container give();

private:
    std::vector<Container> containers();
};
```

Here are getCapacity() and getSize() methods

```
int ContainerStack::getCapacity(){
    return containers.capacity();
}

int ContainerStack::getSize(){
    return containers.size();
}
```

GCC compiles everything without issues, but when using Visual Studio 2017 i get a *E0153 expression must have class type* error. Any way to fix this?

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and the complete error message. What is `Container` ?

Comment: ..and the version of the compilers you used

Comment: ***but when using Visual Studio 2017 i get a E0153 expression must have class type error*** Please post the exact text of the error message. Copy it from the Output Tab instead of the errors list. Also create a minimal example code.

Comment: What gcc are you using?  It doesn't compile here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8fd9762c2b67506

Comment: It doesn't compile on [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GDjapJQ18RBsldjP).

Comment: Container is another object, but that's irrelevant as the issue concerns .capacity() and .size() functions. I used gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)

Comment: @MichałTęgi Errors do not complain about missing `Containter` so your example do not compile on any compiler.

Comment: and after removing obsolete parenthesis it compiles properly on [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EfbRuB4XhTHwhrs7).

Answer (score 5):

You defined `containers` as *a function* returning a vector:

```
std::vector<Container> containers();
```

Fix it to:

```
std::vector<Container> containers;
```

> Why does gcc compile this and msvc doesn't

I suspect you messed up when porting the code from gcc to msvc [as NathanOliver spotted](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8fd9762c2b67506).

Comment: This was the issue, thanks for help. Somehow my defintion got mesed up between 2 projects.

Comment: @MichałTęgi Better than saying "thank you", you can click the checkmark under the answer's score to mark it as accepted. Happy to help.

Comment: ***Somehow my defintion got mesed up between 2 projects*** version control (like git) helps with this.